# Can't connect Docker Wordpress container to MySQL on host

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, virtual-machine

I have an Ubuntu VM that I've spun up on my Mac. In the VM I have MySQL and Docker installed and I'm trying to run a container from a Wordpress image and connect to MySQL on the host vm. The Wordpress image documentation says to use:

```
$ docker run --name some-wordpress -e WORDPRESS_DB_HOST=10.1.2.3:3306 \ -e WORDPRESS_DB_USER=... -e WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD=... -d wordpress
```

I've substituted in the IP address assigned to the host vm and the appropriate user, password and database name environment variables. The container comes up but then shuts down after a short while and the docker logs show:

```
vagrant@docker-blogs:/vagrant$ docker logs je-wordpress 
WordPress not found in /var/www/html - copying now...
Complete! WordPress has been successfully copied to /var/www/html

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused

Warning: mysqli::mysqli(): (HY000/2002): Connection refused in - on line 10

MySQL Connection Error: (2002) Connection refused
```

These repeat several times then it terminates.

Should this be doable? If so, what do need I use as the IP address for the host vm and do I need to configure anything else?

Comment: What is the result of running `ip addr show docker0` on your VM?

Comment: Output is:
`vagrant@docker-blogs:~$ ip addr show docker0

4: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN group default 
    link/ether 02:42:56:4c:20:ff brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.17.0.1/16 scope global docker0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever `

Comment: So instead of using `10.1.2.3` (or whatever you're using) use `172.17.0.1`. That is the ip of your host machine inside the docker0 bridge (that your container is placed on by default). You may also need to do some of what @bartimar describes in his answer, but try this first.

Comment: Got it working now with that IP address and and commenting out the entry in my.cnf as suggested by @bartimar, thanks!  Do you know if there is there a way of setting that IP address, so that it can be used reliably in the future?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have default setting on that mysql.

You are trying to connect to your mysql from DIFFERENT network. This is forbidden by default in mysql.

Look for the setting of mysql:
`grep bind-address /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

`grep skip-networking /etc/mysql/my.cnf`

Comment out both of them (`#bind-address`, ...), or delete them.

restart your mysql service

`service mysql restart`

Allow the user to connect from the remote network. Connect to mysql and execute:

`GRANT ALL ON database.* TO user@'xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx' IDENTIFIED BY 'PASSWORD';`

change the database, user, xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx for the IP you are connecting from, and PASSWORD.

For enabling the IDontGiveADamn mode, just execute

`GRANT ALL ON *.* TO root@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'monkey';`

Comment: Thanks, working now.  I'd already granted the user@'%' - it was a combination of using the correct IP address plus commenting out the bind-address that did the trick.